# Persisting variables outside scope of a function

Tags: c++

This is part of a debugging assignment that I've been stuck on for days. I'm not as much looking for an answer as much as I'm looking for where to look to find the answer.

I have a function that takes an int as a parameter, and the test uses that function to calculate the sum of the range (0,n]. My problem is that I am new to C++ and have exhausted my knowledge of where to look to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, it goes without saying that I cannot modify the test file.

**Header.h**

```
bool getNum(int n);
```

**Header.cpp**:

```
bool getNum(int n)
{
    n = n + 1;

    if (n < 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
int n = 0;
int sum = 0;

while (getNum(n) && n)
{
    sum += n;
}

CHECK(sum == 45);
```

My problem is that I have no way of getting `n` to be `true` to pass the logical &&, so the test never visits the inside of the `while` loop.

Comment: `n` is never `true` or `false` but integers can implicitly convert to `bool`. `0` is converted to `false` anything else to `true`

Comment: Apologies, @idclev463035818. By true I simply mean "not 0," i.e. any instance where ```n``` does not evaluate to ```false```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value of an argument to a function, by taking that argument as a reference:

```
bool getNum(int &n)  // note the reference parameter
{
  // changes to n are visible to the caller of this function
}
```

You have to change the declaration of `getNum` to match as well, of course.

Note that there is no change to the calling code.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/HEgr_2) of a working example.

Comment: One question I do have is that if you are passing by reference, and I refer to "n" inside the function, wouldn't I be referring to the address of n instead of the value stored at that address?

Comment: No, that's not how references work. You'd still to be referring to the value. It's just that the variables inside the loop, refers to the same memory as the variable outside the loop. You could even give them different names.